# Wordpress Not Functioning

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a clients site that was working fine a couple months ago. When I went to it recently it was completely broken. Here is the site: http://cancerhope.com/

I tried to restore it to a backup I have on my computer that I know works but I get the same thing every time. It doesn't matter what backup I use.

I just upgraded MySQL to 5.6 (it was 5.0 before). Neither the backups before or after worked. I also changed the theme in the database to twentyfifteen and deactivated all the plugins but it still didn't work.

Basically the home page shows with no graphics and if I click on a link they just take me to a blank page. If I try to login using standard WP login pages it just goes to a blank white page.

Not sure what to do other than try to rebuild from scratch. Any ideas?

Comment: Who's your hosting provider?

Comment: There are several javascript errors. Have you tried rectifying those? If that doesn't work, I would try reaching out to network solutions.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be a MySQL problem.  It looks like all your requests are being wrapped in a frameset (grabbing content from http://www.oncologydesign.com/), even your scripts.  To see what I mean, open [your jQuery script](http://cancerhope.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.1).  At first glance, it looks okay, but if you view source, you see:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <title>cancerhope.com</title>

</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://www.oncologydesign.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.1" frameborder="0" />
  <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>

<!-- pageok -->
<!-- 01 -->
<!-- -->
</html>
```

Browsers won't parse that properly, as the tags aren't javascript.

Something similar is happening with your CSS (hence the lack of formatting) and your child pages (http://cancerhope.com/consultation/patient-consultation/ is wrapping http://www.oncologydesign.com/consultation/patient-consultation/, which is a blank page).

Without knowing your exact setup, I can't guess why that may be the case.  But hopefully it makes sense to you, and you'll know why that's happening and can fix it.